# A milkman has $80\%$ of milk in his stock of $800$ litres of adulterated milk. How much $100\%$ milk to be added to give certain purity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

**Problem:** A milkman has $80\%$ of milk in his stock of $800$ litres of adulterated milk. How much $100\%$ milk to be added to it so that the purity of milk is between $90\%$ and $95\%$

Let $x$ litres $100\%$ pure  milk need to be added in $800$ litres of milk.

Please suggest further how to proceed not getting any idea on this.

Comment: Hint:  if $80\%$ of $800$ liters is pure, how much pure milk have you got?  If I then add $y$ more pure milk, how much pure milk will I have?  How much fluid in total will I have?

Comment: Is the answer 200

Comment: That's much too low.  Go step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Since, it should also be less than $0.95$ , You get $x<1200$ litres. Continuing from the previous answer of Win Vineeth

Comment: Ya right thank you for that

Comment: You mean $x < 2400$...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using logic rather than algebra. Consider adding the same volume of milk as the original but at 100% purity.

800l @ 80 % (original)
800l @ 100%  (adding same volume at 100% purity)... (1)
= = =
1600l@ 90%   (resultant*, by simple average)
1600l@ 100%  (adding same volume at 100% purity)... (2)
= = =
3200l@ 95%   (resultant*, by simple average)

Hence, from (1) and (1)+(2), you need to add between 800-2400l of 100% milk to give a resultant purity of 90%-95%.

---

*NB: you can take the average of the purity if you add an equal volume as the original.

Answer (score 0):

$80\%$ is milk out of $800$ litres. That gives - you have $640$ litres of pure milk. 
 Now, $640+x\over {800+x}$$>0.9$ 
 That gives $x>800$ litres. Since, it should also be less than $0.95$ , You get $x<1200$ litres.

Comment: You mean $x < 2400$

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 800 l total

640 milk

160 water.

Make that 160 10 percent.

So total 1600. 
Add 1600-640. That is 960l of pure milk

Comment: Don't forget to also subtract the water fraction